# Icono .jpg desde una carpeta, JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java

Estoy usando un **JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog** para Mostrar una imagen adjunta desde una carpeta llamada "img" que esta dentro del mismo proyecto, Adicional a la imagen en el JOptionPane se ve una pregunta sacada de `Preguntas[Npre]`, a la cual el usuario respondera, En la declaracion del Icono uso las variables tipo int `Npre` y `Nres` para sacar la imagen correspondiente a esa pregunta, Pero al ejecutarlo no me sale la imagen, Estoy usando NetBeans IDE 8.2 y el fragmento de codigo es:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, Preguntas[Npre], "Pregunta #" + Intentos, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon("src/img/" + Npre + "-" + Nres + ".jpg"),null, null);
```

Todas las imagenes son .jpg y los nombres de estas coinciden, Tengo mal la ruta del icono?, o es algun problema con los otros parametros?

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna clase donde implementes la interfaz de `Icon`?

Comment: Todo eso se encuentra dentro de una clase y mas especificamente dentro de un metodo, Pero el unico lugar donde hago uso del `ImageIcon` es en esa linea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!Buenas!

Para insertar un icono en el `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` debes de crear una clase aparte que implemente la interfaz `Icon` de esta manera:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class IconoTest implements Icon{

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        Image image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Imagen/test.jpg")).getImage();
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return 50;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return 50;
    }
}
```

Donde aquí escribes la ruta de tu imagen:

```
getResource("Imagen/test.jpg")).getImage();
```

La imagen, una buena opción es ubicarla en la carpeta **src**.

Despues en tu clase principal, la clase `main`. Creas una instancia de la clase icono que hayas creado de esta manera:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        IconoTest icon = new IconoTest();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mensaje dentro de la ventana", "Titulo", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, icon);

    }

}
```

Y dentro de ese `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` te he dejado lo que debes de introducir en cada apartado, donde por ultimo es el objeto icono que hayas creado.

**EDITO**

Te dejo este enlace donde explican todo lo que se puede realizar con un `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` y viene bien explicado el como hacerlo.

[Explicación de JOptionPane](https://serprogramador.es/programando-mensajes-de-dialogo-en-java-parte-1/)